# ListView items not displaying

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

In my xamarin forms app I input book name which should be displayed in ListView. But there is not a single line in ListView and I can't figure where I made a mistake. I use both Prism and MVVM.

Here is the xaml

```
<ListView  SeparatorColor="Black" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding BookList}"
           HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label Text="{Binding BookName}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And there is a list and method which is called after the button is pressed.

```
private BookModel book = new BookModel();
private ObservableCollection<BookModel> _bookList = new ObservableCollection<BookModel>();
private ObservableCollection<BookModel> BookList
{
   get { return _bookList ; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _bookList , value); }

}

public async override void getBook(string data)
{
   book = new BookModel
    {
       BookName = data
    };
    BookList.Add(book);
}
```

and model

```
public class BookModel
{
  public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

Previously what worked for me was just a simple ListView without any datatemplate and added book to list by `BookList.Add(data)` where `data` is what I input in app.

Comment: are you sure `getBook()` is getting called?  Where does the value for `data` come from?

Comment: Like I said at the end `data` is what I input in app(in that case it's book name) and `getBook()` gets called because the way of calling it didn't change and I used it before with success. I ran a debug and everything is okey with `data`.

Comment: ObservableCollection should be a public property. If you want to use Binding

Comment: @TomášZachoval thanks.. I didn't even notice that I set it to private :D

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, the OP says that making the collection property public solved the problem. They needed to change this:

```
private ObservableCollection<BookModel> BookList
```

To this:

```
public ObservableCollection<BookModel> BookList
```

This is based on [@Tomáš Zachoval's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422423/listview-items-not-displaying/70426238#comment124486786_70422423).